# Automaticly change page when user select position in Choice List Widget

Tags: symfony, twig

How to automatically change page (save result and reload page with new data) when user choose value form list. I'll plan skip the submit button `->add('save', SubmitType::class);`

I work on Symfony 3. Form function:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
  $builder
    ->add('userChoice', ChoiceType::class, array(
            'choices'      => array(
                                '1' => 'one', 
                                '2' => 'two'),
        ))
    ;
 }
```

How to do it?

Comment: there is nothing to do for symfony, you need to check onchange from javascript, and send data for saving, rendering new template, etc.

Comment: @kRicha normally I add form only  ** {{ form(form) }}** in TWIG page, and in controller supports the action when  someone is submit button.  Do you give me any example?

Comment: yeah, but you have wrote that you wish to skip submit button, so you need to add javascript, that will be track changes in your select or checkbox (i don't know) and if it changes you could serialize your form and send it to some action for data processing.